# Bootstrap-table filter-control extension populating select with complete list of options

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table for working with data from my database.

I use the pagination features and only send back the number of rows requested by the user using the limit and offset options.

I am also using the table-control extension to allow for easy filtering of the results.  However when I use a the select control for filtering with data-filter-control="select" the entries are just those returned within that set of results.

As I apply other filters the list will grow.  I would like to use the API and have it preload a list of all possible items from the server for that list to allow for filtering via those options.

While I can send the results back with each filtered set of results, perhaps in a separate element of the JSON, it would likely be best to load this list after the control itself loads as I do not constantly need to be sending that set of data to the control with each filter.

Is this possible?  Can I use the API to preload this list with a set of values?

There is an issue on github that seems to describe a similar issue to what I'm having https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/904 and note of a patch, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

I am using bootstrap 3.3.4 from maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com and I am using bootstrap-table 1.8.1 via cdnjs.cloudflare.com

Edit:
I have figured this out after using FireBug to step through the code line by line to figure out if I could do this.

There are two options for supplying data to the filter.  Add the attribute data-filter-data to the .  You can utilize a "var" or "url" option followed by an underscore (or some other character that gets discarded) and then in the case of "var" pass it an object name, mine looks like this data-filter-data="var_OnlineValues" and utlizes my object var OnlineValues = { "": "", "Started" : "Started", "Submitted" : "Submitted" }.  I also have some data on the server that I am returning as JSON.  data-filter-data="url_filename.php" and the object returned is a key/value pair.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

**Usage**
Add `data-filter-data` attribute to the column.

Example:

```
<script>
var payment_methods = {
  "PP": "PayPal - PP",
  "CC": "PayPal - CC"
};
</script>

<th data-field="payment_method" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="select" data-filter-data="var:payment_methods">Payment Method</th>
```

There's no document for the `filterData` option, so I had to read the code.  I quoted the relevant part below. There is `substring(0,3)` and the valid value is `url` or `var`.  The next character is ignored.

If the type is `url` it makes the ajax call to populate the response JSON into the select options.  The structure is simple {key:value}.

If the type is `var` it looks up `window[filterDataSource]` which is the global variable specified by the option. The data structure is simple {key:value} object.

```
    if (column.filterData !== undefined && column.filterData.toLowerCase() !== 'column') {
        var filterDataType = column.filterData.substring(0, 3);
        var filterDataSource = column.filterData.substring(4, column.filterData.length);
        var selectControl = $('.' + column.field);
        addOptionToSelectControl(selectControl, '', '');

        switch (filterDataType) {
            case 'url':
                $.ajax({
                    url: filterDataSource,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                            addOptionToSelectControl(selectControl, key, value);
                        });
                    }
                });
                break;
            case 'var':
                var variableValues = window[filterDataSource];
                for (var key in variableValues) {
                    addOptionToSelectControl(selectControl, key, variableValues[key]);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Really well done. It works perfectly. (the var part only tested)

Answer (score 7):

You do not need to modify bootstrap table to make this work. There is a way to set default values to the dropdown select using the `data-filter-data` property of the columns. try adding the following:

to the head:

```
<head>
    // ... included scripts go here also
    <script>
        var filterDefaults = {
            somekey: 'some string value',
            anotherkey: 'another value'
        };
    </script>
</head>
```

then, add `data-filter-data:'var:filterDefaults'` to the column:

```
<table id="table"
      data-toggle="table"
      data-filter-control="true">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th data-field="id">ID</th>
             <th data-field="name" data-filter-control="input">Item Name</th>
             <th data-field="price" data-filter-control="select" data-filter-data="var:filterDefaults">Item Price</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```